# Align contents of a Listview using JavaFX

Tags: listview, javafx, alignment

I am trying to Center align the contents of my list view

```
private ListView<String> library = new ListView<String>();
ObservableList<String> libraryList = FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList();
```

I have found ways to do it using CSS and XML however i am looking for ways to do it in java, anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a custom `CellFactory` and custom `ListCell` for the `ListView`.

Here is a complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple UI
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();

        // Setup the cell factory for the listview. It will hold lists of HBoxes that can be aligned
        listView.setCellFactory(stringListView -> new CenteredListViewCell());

        // Sample data
        listView.getItems().setAll("One", "Two", "Three", "Four");

        root.getChildren().add(listView);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

final class CenteredListViewCell extends ListCell<String> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            // Create the HBox
            HBox hBox = new HBox();
            hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            // Create centered Label
            Label label = new Label(item);
            label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            hBox.getChildren().add(label);
            setGraphic(hBox);
        }
    }
}
```

What you're doing is creating a custom `CenteredListViewCell` that uses a `HBox` as its main content. Setting the alignment for the `HBox` allows you to center the `Label` within it.

Then with `listView.setCellFactory(stringListView -> new CenteredListViewCell());` in your controller, you are telling the `ListView` to use the custom cell instead of the standard Java implementation.

*This may be able to be simplified and I welcome comments and edits!*

Comment: `static final class CenteredListViewCell extends ListCell<String> { { setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER); } @Override protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) { super.updateItem(item, empty); setText(item); } }`